# modify item content in vis.js dataset on click

Tags: javascript, vis.js

we have created a dataset with the following items :

```
var items = new vis.DataSet([
{id: 1, content: 'item 1', start: moment('8:00', "hh:mm"), end: moment('9:00', "hh:mm")},
{id: 2, content: 'item 2', start: moment('9:00', "hh:mm")},
{id: 3, content: 'item 3', start: moment('10:00', "hh:mm")},
{id: 4, content: 'item 4', start: moment('11:00', "hh:mm")}
```

Now what we want to do is to be able to click on `item1` for example and change its content; I've tried to use the function `dataset.update`:

```
items.on('*', function (event, properties, senderId) {
   var itemId = timeline.getSelection(); 
 items.update({id: timeline.getSelection(), content: 'updated', start: moment('9:00', "hh:mm")}); 
});
```

but we get this error:

> Property 'content' missing in item 2.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt tested your code snippet, but the problem could be that "timeline.getSelection" returns a array of ids and "items.update" accept only a single object or a array of objects as "data" argument.

Solution 1:
You need to loop thru the selection array, create a data object for every entry and pass it to "items.update".

Solution 2:
Prepare a array of objects and pass the array to "items.update".

Reference:
- visjs.org/docs/timeline/index.html#Methods -> getSelection()
- http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html#Methods -> update(data [, senderId])